# I am trying to cut one Object plane using another object plane

Tags: objects

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33EFb.jpg

[image: Cutting issue]

I am trying to cut that cross out of the plane you see around it. The cross is made of multiple objects because it can fold up. The problem is I can't seem to get the bool tool to cut them out of the large plane. Maybe its not working because they are both flat. Anyways I need solution to this problem. any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do the "Knife Project" option. Here's a breakdown from Blender: [image]

I tried it in a quick project that I set up similar to yours and it worked well for me. Let me know if you need more help! The Knife Project option can be found in edit mode under the "Mesh" menu.

Comment: This worked well thankyou

Comment: You bet! Cheers.